# Typescript version in VScode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have a CRA app in VSCode.
My global TS version is:
[image]

My project TS version is (package.json):
[image]

VSCode uses the latest:
[image]

Now, when I try to add a 4.0 TS feature, the terminal shows a compilation error:
[image]

[image]

I tried to change the package.json TS version to latest and ran npm install but it didn't help.

My Questions are:

1. Why doesn't it compile?
2. Which TS version is used for PROBLEMS pane and which for terminal? I would expect the same error in both locations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should probably either use the latest version or configure VSCode to use the workspace version. Open Command Palette > Select TypeScript Version.

Comment: It is configured to use the latest version

Answer (score 0):

When you run `tsc -v` in the terminal, you are calling a **globally** installed Typescript package which is showing you have version 4.8.4 installed.

You can verify this by running `npm list -g --depth 0` which will list all the global packages you have installed, along with their versions.

However, when using npm scripts (e.g in CRA `npm run build`) the Typescript package inside your **node_modules** folder is called. Since this version of Typescript is 3.x the compilation will fail. By changing VSCode to use the workspace version, the same error will be shown.

[image: using workspace ts version]

[image: syntax error intellisense]

Upgrading the version inside your package.json to the latest should fix this error. To be sure the correct version is being used, try using an npm script to list the version by including this **vers** script in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "...": "your other scripts",
  "vers": "tsc -v"
}
```

then run `npm run vers` in your terminal.

---

TLDR:

Q1.

- The Typescript version used when running the CRA build script (3.x)
  is targeted which will fail when using 4.x syntax.

Q2.

- The problems pane in VSCode uses the VSCode Typescript version
  (depends how up to date your VSCode is) unless manually switched to
  use the workspace version (node_modules version).
- The terminal will target your globally installed version.
- NPM scripts will target the version inside your node_modules folder.

Comment: thanks for your elaborated reply!
As I wrote, I tried to change the package.json TS version to latest (4.8+) and ran npm install but it didn't help.